# rocketmq-client cannot consumer message

Tags: message-queue, rocketmq

I am using rocketmq 4.3.1 client,Now I have encountered some problems. A consumer group that has been using it for a while has some unconsumed messages. Now I am new to the message queue, the consumer can't consume it normally, I have to restart the consumer service to consume the message. But I changed to a consumer group, and the consumer can get the message in the message queue center in real time.I want to know the reason for this problem.thanks a lot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTuph.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjH43.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason, because the druid in the service of the rocketmq consumer has been retrying to connect to the database, causing the consumer to no longer get the message.

Comment: rocketmq consumer may has nothing to do with database?Why do you say about db?